# Geoserver manager, adding a new layer

Tags: java, rest, geoserver

While programatically creating a new layer with the geoserver-manager api (http://code.google.com/p/geoserver-manager/wiki/Documentation) using the following code:

```
GeoServerRESTPublisher publisher = new GeoServerRESTPublisher(RESTURL, RESTUSER, RESTPW);

GSFeatureTypeEncoder featureTypeEncoder = new GSFeatureTypeEncoder();
featureTypeEncoder.setSRS("EPSG:41001");
featureTypeEncoder.setName("view1");
featureTypeEncoder.setNativeBoundingBox(10,10,100,100, "EPSG:41001");

GSLayerEncoder layerEncoder = new GSLayerEncoder();
layerEncoder.setEnabled(true);

boolean ok = publisher.publishDBLayer(WORKSPACE, "user1", featureTypeEncoder, layerEncoder);
```

The new layer is created successfully but it's the wrong type (point not line).  Is there a way of changing this layer type (to line) either before or after creating the layer?

Versions:
Geoserver 2.3.0
Postgres 1.14
Geoserver-manager 1.3.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

2 ways:
you have to use the layer encoder to configure the default layer:

```
        GSLayerEncoder layerEncoder = new GSLayerEncoder();
        layerEncoder.setEnabled(true);
        layerEncoder.setQueryable(true);
        layerEncoder.setDefaultStyle("polygon");

        boolean published = publisher.publishDBLayer(WORKSPACE, STORENAME, FTENCODER, layerEncoder);
```

you could try the configure the layer after the publish:

```
    String layerName = ...;
    String newStyleName = ...;
    GeoServerRESTPublisher publisher = ...;

    GSLayerEncoder le = new GSLayerEncoder();
    le.setDefaultStyle(newStyleName);
    publisher.configureLayer(le, layerName);
```

Cheers,
Carlo Cancellieri

Ref:

- https://github.com/geosolutions-it/geoserver-manager/wiki/Publishing-Layers-Advanced
- https://github.com/geosolutions-it/geoserver-manager/blob/1.3.x/src/main/java/it/geosolutions/geoserver/rest/encoder/GSLayerEncoder.java#L126